# Hide textbox if data is available in table

Tags: jquery

I have a sign-up form, which of course shows up blank.  When the user types in a couple of letters of the team captain, autocomplete displays available choices and fills in phone number and email address if they exist.  What I am trying to do is hide the divs for the email address and phone number IF they already exist.  If they don't exist, the user can fill in the textbox and the data will be written into the table.

Here is what I am trying to get to work:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($("#capphone").text().length > 0) {
            $("#tm_info2").hide();
        };

        if ($("#capemail").text().length > 0) {
            $("#tm_info1").hide();
        };
    });
```

Am I headed in the right direction or totally out in left field?  As always, thanks for the input!

Comment: Have you tested your theory? do you have a link to a demo or anything?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.  You can see what I am trying to do at http://hammerpins.net/signup_HPtest.php?eid=392&squads=2.  If you type in De my name will show up and if you select me, my phone and email address will autopopulate.  Because the data is there, the divs for both email and phone should hide.  They do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- `.text().length` wont return anything, you need to go with
  `.val().length` as that returns the length of the VALUE of the input
  element.
- The if tests you are running occur on $(document).ready. They really
  need to occur AFTER you click on an auto complete item as the input
  fields are only populated once an auto complete item is selected.
- You really need a way of differentiating between the autocomplete
  filling in the field and a user manually filling in the field.

Without access to your autocomplete code i cannot 100% answer your question, but put the following in a function that is called when you click on an auto complete name:

```
 if ($("#capphone").val().length > 0) {
     $("#tm_info2").hide();
 };

 if ($("#capemail").val().length > 0) {
     $("#tm_info1").hide();
 };
```

Comment: Thanks, Damien.  Was out of town at my daughter's wedding, which is why it took so long for me to get back to you.  I do have a question to comment #3.  Why does it matter whether the information is autofilled or completed by the user?  As soon as the data entered by the user does not match what is already on the table, the autocomplete stops.  When the user has finished entering the information, assuming that is does not already exist, the code will add the information to the table for the next time.